# How can I implement the Facebook Ads API with C#?

Tags: c#, .net, facebook, api, facebook-ads-api

I've been searching for an answer for a while, but I couldn't find any relevant libraries\documentation for C# implentation of the Facebook Ads API. I've checked Facebook's developers portal ofcourse, but they only offer PHP and Python code samples.

Any information is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: close: SO isn't a tutorial site

Answer (score 2):

For those still looking for an answer (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3729490/how-to-access-facebook-ads-api-using-asp-net)), I recently released an unofficial SDK for C#. The code is available on GitHub [here](https://github.com/Paradoxis/facebook-csharp-ads-sdk).

It implements most of the GET requests that are available by acting as a wrapper for the Facebook SDK for C#. Hope it helps anyone at all.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Facebook API doesn't support C# SDK now.

I think there are two ways to walk around this:

1. Use cURL, there are some [Classes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.110).aspx) to support cURL request/response
2. Use a Python/PHP interface for Facebook access, and you could use cross-language framework like [Thrift](https://thrift.apache.org/) to make call from your original C# program.

Wish this useful.